# Function passed for for child component don't work in ReactJS with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm passing a function from parent to child component, this function is to updated a value in the state parent component. The pass is working just fine and in the child component i can access the function, but when i try change the value is not changed when i click in the button and call the "handleAddClass" function. The data send to a API is working too.

The h1 {setupProgressTeacher.classesByTeacher} /h1 in the parent is not changed when the value is updated in child.

**The parent component**

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useCallback, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Container } from './styled';
import Navbar from '../../components/NavBar';
import AddClass from '../TeacherSetup/addclass';
import api from '../../services/api';

interface TeacherSetupState {
  classesByTeacher: number;
}

const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {

  const [setupProgressTeacher, setSetupProgressTeacher] = useState<TeacherSetupState>(() => {

    const classesByTeacher = 1;

    return { classesByTeacher } as TeacherSetupState;
  });


  const updateStateProgress = useCallback((classesByTeacher: number) => {
    setSetupProgressTeacher({ classesByTeacher });
  }, []);


  useLayoutEffect(() => {

    async function fetchData() {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('@Ensae:token');

      const response = await api.get('/class/classbyteacher', {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });

    }
    fetchData();

  }, []);


  return (
    <Container>
      <Navbar />

      <h1>{setupProgressTeacher.classesByTeacher}</h1>
      <AddClass setProgress={(({ classesByTeacher: any }) => updateStateProgress)} />

      {/* <AddSubject /> */}
    </Container >

  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

**The child component**

```
import React, { useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Content } from './styled';
import { Form } from '@unform/web';
import api from '../../services/api';
import { SiGoogleclassroom } from 'react-icons/si';
import { FormHandles } from '@unform/core';
import Input from '../../components/Form/input';
import Button from '../../components/Button';


interface AddClassData {
  class_name: string;
}

interface TeacherSetupState {
  setProgress: ({ classesByTeacher }: { classesByTeacher: any }) => void;
}

const AddClass: React.FC<TeacherSetupState> = (props) => {
  const formRef = useRef<FormHandles>(null);


  const handleAddClass = useCallback(async (data: AddClassData) => {

    const userStoraged = localStorage.getItem('@Ensae:user');

    let userObject;

    if (typeof userStoraged === 'string') {
      userObject = JSON.parse(userStoraged);
    }

    const dataForApi = {
      class_name: data.class_name,
      lesson_frequency: "Semanal",
      teacher_id: userObject.id,
    }
    try {

      await api.post('/class', dataForApi);



    } catch (err) {

    }

    props.setProgress({ classesByTeacher: 4 });

  }, [props]);

  return (
    <Content>
      <h2>Agora que fez o primeiro login, está na hora de criar uma turma</h2>
      <Form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleAddClass}>

        <div className="inputClassName" >
          <Input name="class_name" className="inputAddClass" icon={SiGoogleclassroom} placeholder="O nome da turma" />

          <Button type="submit">Continuar</Button>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </Content>
  );
};

export default AddClass;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line right here:

```
<AddClass setProgress={(({ classesByTeacher: any }) => updateStateProgress)} />
```

`setProgress` is a function which takes an argument that is an object containing `classesByTeacher` and then **doesn't use that argument**.

You want to **call** `updateStateProgress` with that argument.  Note that `({ classesByTeacher: any }) =>` actually means that we are renaming the value of property `classesByTeacher` to a variable called `any` when we destructure it, not that we are annotating the type.

```
<AddClass 
   setProgress={({ classesByTeacher }) => updateStateProgress(classesByTeacher)}
/>
```

You could also just pass down the `updateStateProgess` function, but you would need to change the interface  for `AddClass`'s props accordingly.